# How to avoid half code executing in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script with several mysql queries. Once I run this script it executes first two queries and server error will be occurred.(It will happen any where). The other queries are not executed.This case make a huge problem. Because some tables are updated and others are not updated. I want to avoid this problem. Are their any solutions..?

Comment: Did you tried putting all of your queries into a single transaction?

Comment: _the internet connection is down_, What?? Do you mean server error? Does your script take a long request?

Comment: One you've sent your request, the server doesn't care if your internet connection is up or not, the code executes on the server, not on your machine. It looks like you have an error somewhere in your code that prevent those queries from executing, it's not because of your internet connection.

Comment: As per question title, maybe try to suit yourself with .ini config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these queries in your code

```
START TRANSACTION or BEGIN start a new transaction.

COMMIT commits the current transaction, making its changes permanent.

ROLLBACK rolls back the current transaction, canceling its changes.

SET autocommit disables or enables the default autocommit mode for the current session.
```

More info on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

My suggestion is Start your code by using first query as `START Transaction` then execute your queries , In the end use `COMMIT`

Answer (score 0):

Read up on MySQLi transaction, commit and rollback

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

This would solve your problem, if you start a transaction. You can then execute all the queries you need and then put a commit behind. If the commit is never triggered than an automatic rollback will ensue.